# Python and Tkinter GUI - How to Add Id Automatically and Increment by 1 After Each Submission?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, form-submit

I want to make a GUI that user inputs customer information, but I want to add an id to each customer so that when I search for that ID I can find the customer. After each submission, the id should increase one by one.

For example, the first customer should have an id of CUS1001 and when I submit the customer, the second customer should have an id of CUS1002. Since the number of customers cannot be tracked, the id cannot be entered manually.

The code that I have done so far is attached below. I appreciate it if you can help me with this.

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.simpledialog
import csv
from tkinter import messagebox

def store_member():

afirstname = firstname.get()
asurname = surname.get()
aemail = email.get()
aemailaddress = emailaddress.get()
fullemail = aemail + aemailaddress
print(fullemail)
aday = day.get()
amonth = month.get()
ayear = year.get()
date_of_birth = aday + "." + amonth + "." + ayear
print(date_of_birth)

agender_choice = gender_choice.get()
amobile = mobile.get()
fullmobile = "44" + amobile

if afirstname == "" or asurname == "" or aemail == "" or amobile == "":
    print('Error')
    messagebox.showerror("error", "there was an error")
    firstname.set("")
    surname.set("")
    email.set("")
    mobile.set("")

elif agender_choice > 2:
    print('Error 2')
    messagebox.showerror("error" , "please select a gender")
    firstname.set("")
    surname.set("")
    email.set("")
    mobile.set("")

elif(len(fullmobile)!=12):
    print( 'Error 3')
    messagebox.showerror("error" , "the mobile prone numebr is incomplete")
    firstname.set("")
    surname.set("")
    email.set("")
    mobile.set("")

else:
    result = messagebox.askquestion("Submit" , "You are about the enter the data\n" + afirstname + "\n" + asurname +"\n" + fullemail + "\n" )

    if(result == 'yes'):
        print('here')

        with open('customer.txt' , 'a') as csvfile:
            writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
            writer.writerow([afirstname,asurname,fullemail,date_of_birth,agender_choice,amobile])
        csvfile.close()
    else:
        firstname.set("")
        surname.set("")
        email.set("")
        mobile.set("")

def back():
    print('here')

def clear_enter_screen():
    firstname.set("")
    surname.set("")
    email.set("")
    emailaddress.set("@hotmail.com")
    day.set("1")
    month.set("January")
    year.set("2018")
    mobile.set("")

def help_entry():
    messagebox.showinfo("Information" , "Enter all data fully")

root = Tk()
root.config(background = 'light grey')

#defining all variables for each gui component
firstname = StringVar()
surname = StringVar()
email = StringVar()
emailaddress = StringVar()
day = StringVar()
month = StringVar()
year = StringVar()
gender_choice = IntVar()
mobile = StringVar()

#gui components for each row
#ROW 0
lblHeading = Label(root, text = "New Customer" , font = ('Arial' , 24 , "bold")).grid(row = 0, column = 0, columnspan = 4, padx=20, pady=10)

#row1
lblFirstName = Label(root, text = "First Name" , font= ('Arial', 14, "bold")).grid(row=1, column=1)
entryFirstName = Entry(root, textvariable = firstname, width = 10). grid(row=1, column=2)

#row 2
lblLastName = Label(root, text = "Last Name" , font = ('Arial' , 14, "bold")).grid(row = 2, column =1)
entryLastName = Entry(root, textvariable = surname, width = 10).grid(row=2 , column=2)

# row 3
lblGender = Label(root, text = "Gender" , font = ('Arial', 14, "bold")).grid(row=3, column=0)
radiobutton1 = Radiobutton(root, text = "Male", variable= gender_choice, value=1, font=('Arial', 14, "bold")).grid(row=3, column=1)
radiobutton2 = Radiobutton(root, text = "Female", variable=gender_choice,value=2, font=('Arial',14,"bold")).grid(row=3, column=2)

#row4
lblemail = Label(root,text ="Email", font=('Arial',14, "bold")).grid(row=4, column = 0)

#entry box
entryemail = Entry(root, textvariable = email, width = 10).grid(row=4, column=1)
#drop down list
list1 = ['@hotmail.com', '@gmail.com' , '@yahoo.com']
droplist = OptionMenu(root, emailaddress, *list1)
droplist.config(width = 15)
emailaddress.set('@hotmail.com')
droplist.grid(row=4, column=2)

#row5
lblbirthday = Label(root, text = 'birthday' , font=('Arial' , 14, 'bold')).grid(row=5 , column=0)
list2 = ['1', '2', '3' , '4' , '5']
droplist = OptionMenu(root,day,*list2)
droplist.config(width=5)
day.set('1')
droplist.grid(row=5, column=1)

list3 = ['January', 'February', 'March']
droplist = OptionMenu(root,month,*list3)
droplist.config(width=15)
month.set('January')
droplist.grid(row=5, column=2)

list4 = ['2021', '2022', '2023']
droplist = OptionMenu(root, year, *list4)
droplist.config(width=8)
year.set('2021')
droplist.grid(row=5, column=3)

#row6 components
lblmobile= Label(root, text= "mobile +44" , font=('Arial' , 14, "bold")).grid(row=6, column=1)
entrymobile = Entry(root, textvariable = mobile, width=10).grid(row=6, column=2)

#row7 buttons
submit_button = Button(root,text = "Store", command=store_member , bg='orange', fg='white').grid(row=7, column=0, sticky=E, padx=20, pady=18)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Suggest to use `sqlite3` database, which supports auto-increment field, to store the customer records.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the suggestion, but I want to do it on a csv file.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using csv then use this method:

first create "id.txt" then

add function

```
def customer_id():
    with open ("id.txt", 'r') as file:
        pre_id=file.read()
    new_id="CUS"+str(int(pre_id[3:])+1)
    with open("id.txt",'w') as file:
        file.write(new_id)
    return new_id



#warning: for the above function the prefix should be CUS(or any 3 letter word)

#note: I can't achieve id as "CUS0001" the above function give id as "CUS1"
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I have modified your idea. I have written the first customer maunally in to the csv, giving the id of 1. Then, before each submission of new customer, I am taking the first value of the last row and incrementing by 1. After that combining word into a string.

Comment: welcome, and your idea is good then mine.